# How to pass the current instance into the constructor of another class withon class declaration?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a service that returns me a list of entities, for example:

```kotlin
data class TypeDto(
        val type: Type,
        val stages: List<StageDto>)
```

After applying several `filter` and `flatMap` operations, I get the desired data that has the following structure:

```kotlin
data class CustomerDto(
        val id: String,
        val name: String)
```

In order to extract the logic of filtering and mapping, I made a `CustomerDtoWrapper` class that takes `List<TypeDto>` as a constructor argument and does all the collection manipulation. So, in the end it looks as follows:

```kotlin
val types = service.getTypes()
val customers = CustomerDtoWrapper(types).filteredCustomers()
```

But I would like to make it more fluent and easy to read. Is it possible to call a certain function after `getTypes()`, so that `types` will be of the `CustomerDtoWrapper` type and look as follows:

```kotlin
val types = service.getTypes().someFun { ... }
val customers = types.filteredCustomers()
```

Comment: After experimenting with scope functions, I found the following solution to work: `service.getTypes().let { CustomerDtoWrapper(it) }`. Currious, if it's the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can write for example extension function for this:

```kotlin
fun List<TypeDto>.toFilteredCustomers() = CustomerDtoWrapper(this).filteredCustomers()
```

and use it like this:

```
val customers = service.getTypes().toFilteredCustomers()
```

Comment: This. I actually would skip the whole CustomerDtoWrapper class and just do the collection filtering and mapping in the `toFilteredCustomers()` function directly

Comment: @MathiasHenze, in that case, you can just move all logic to the extension function I guess